# Pass variable vs access class field

Tags: java, oop

I have got a question regarding program style. Within a class, is it better to pass a variable to a method or to access the field inside a method?

```
public class NumberTest{
   private int num;

   public NumberTest (int num){
      this.num = num;      
      calculateX(num);
      calculateY();
   }

   private void calculateX(int num){
      System.out.println (num);
   }

   private void calculateY(){
      System.out.println(num)
   }           
}
```

Comment: It's unlikely to make a difference either way.

Comment: Disagree, there's a difference with regard to unit testing - please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll differ from the others here...

Where it is at all *reasonable*, I like to pass in the argument.  This very slightly decouples the method from the class implementation, and makes it easier to unit test.  For example, sometimes it is a pretty complex process to set `this.num` to 94404 due to other constraints.

e.g. this is a Zip Code but your business logic requires that it must match the State and Country field.  Or, in practice this field is read from a Database, a Web Site, etc...

If you pass the argument, your unit test can shortcut and just pass in the value.  And, in the off chance you might have a future special case where you don't want to use what's in the class field, you can do it.

Now, if you are using 27 class fields, you obviously don't want to pass in 27 arguments.  But, IMO, if it's 1 or 2, I like to pass them in.

Minor Noted added after acceptance:

There is another possible difference between passing in the arg and using a field.  In a multi-threaded environment, using a passed in argument *may* be safer that reading from a field.  The field might get changed in the middle of the function, while a passed in argument, depending on type and usage, is less likely to change.  In this example, a passed in `int num` will never change unexpectedly, but `this.num` might.

Answer (score 1):

You're already passing the object (as `this`) when you call a member function anyway.  You don't gain anything from having to explicitly specify the argument too, unless you need to be able to use that same function with values other than `this.num`.

Short version: Use the latter, unless you need to `calculateX(some_whole_other_number)`.

Answer (score 1):

those methods might look kinda similar to you, since they give you the same result, but they're actually very very different from each-other.

For instance, suppose your `NumberText` method looked like

```
public NumberTest (int num){
   this.num = num;


   calculateX(num * 2);
   calculateY();
}
```

`calculateX` wouldn't actually take the field, but it can take something completely different.

A general rule of thumb is

If it makes sense to pass in something other than `num` to `calculateX` than you probably should pass it in.  otherwise, don't

also, if you do this

```
private void calculateX(int num){
   System.out.println (num);
}
```

change the parameter name to something other than `num`

Answer (score 0):

Is num some state of NumberTest? Will you need it later? If so, make it a field.

Does NumberTest just provide function calculateX for many nums? If so make calculateX static.